# Create php variable from URL without get

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm generating a download link which I sent through email to download a pdf file. There are some parameters (base64 encoded) in the download link to verify the correct profile/user. I want to be the download link as follows:

www.example.com/download/ZW5jb2RlbXljb2Rl

The parameters are directly added after the subdirectory.
I know it can be done with php GET as follows:
www.example.com/download/index.php?base64=ZW5jb2RlbXljb2Rl

But in my opinion it is nicer to use the first URL. Except I have no idea how to accomplish this with php.
My guess I have to make a rewrite in htaccess?

I found this thread: [Rewriting a URL to a PHP parameter from inside a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604954/rewriting-a-url-to-a-php-parameter-from-inside-a-subdirectory)

But I already have some htaccess rewrites (JOOMLA), and it is just for the only folder...

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: So you already know the answer is you need a rewrite rule. But you don't want to add another rewrite rule.  So what can anyone possibly say to this?

Comment: You could use: `www.example.com/download/index.php/ZW5jb2RlbXljb2Rl` and the string would be available in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. Else, you would need another rewrite rule.

Comment: I used Panama Jack's answer, he suggested an URL rewrite. Thx for ur help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no choice but to use rewrite for this **That's what it's for.**

> But I already have some htaccess rewrites (JOOMLA), and it is just for
>   the only folder..

This absolutely does not matter. Your Apache setup can contain as many rewrites as you need. I've seen 100's.

So you could just add these rules `above` your current Joomla rules and it should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)/?$ /download/index.php?base64=$1 [L]
```

Otherwise you would have to do what Jonathan said and use `index.php` in your URL.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I used this Rewrite and solved everything for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` to see your current page.
You can explode the string after the last `/` using that:

```
$filename = explode('/', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

That way if your link is www.example.com/download/ZW5jb2RlbXljb2Rl, then filename value will be "ZW5jb2RlbXljb2Rl".

I'm not sure if that's your question, but that should work depending on the usage.

Comment: You would need a rewrite rule or else that URL would just thrown a 404 error.