# Convert url slash to parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to convert url like this

```
www.domain.tld/long/param
```

to this

```
www.domain.tld/long/long.php?l=param
```

I have CMS on same server and i dont wan't to mess up it's htaccess so this should work only on that specific directory (long).

Tried this but it wont work:
[Rewriting a URL to a PHP parameter from inside a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604954/rewriting-a-url-to-a-php-parameter-from-inside-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `long/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ long.php?l=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this .htaccess file in the long dir.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ long.php?l=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$ long.php?l=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.cvs$ long.php?l=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml$ long.php?l=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```